# How to get all the data for the current date in ms Access using python?

Tags: python, ms-access

This is the picture of my data in access:

[image: MS-ACESS table]

And below is the code for getting all the data for the current month:

```
def access():
    l =[]
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\GOBOTIX\Desktop\dbSamp64.mdb;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from Table1 where Month(DateTime)=Month(Date())')

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        l.append(row)
```

How can I obtain all the data for the current date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the answer that you are looking for be as simple as:

```
select * from Table1 where [DateTime] >= Date() and [DateTime] < Date()+1
```

Alternatively:

```
select * from Table1 where DateValue([DateTime]) = Date()
```